# how to implement csrf without csrf token in django

Tags: python, django

In django, if I want to use csrf token, I need to imbed a form with csrf token in django template. However as a backend-engineer I am co-working with a front-end engineer whose code is not available for me. So I caanot use the template. In this case, if I want still the csrf function. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

you should ask the coworker to embed the csrf token in the form he is sending you

you can get it from `document.Cookies` if he doesnt want to or cannot use the `{% csrf %}` tag

Answer (score 0):

You may use `@csrf_exempt` decorator to except csrf tokens.

First, import decorator

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
```

Then add `@csrf_exempt` before your view.

```
@csrf_exempt
def my_view(request):
return HttpResponse('Hello world')
```

More details can be found here [enter link description here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt)